interaction between latex2sympy and sympy.symbols()
I'm not understanding the interaction between latex2sympy and sympy.symbols() properly.
If I run the program
import sympy as sym
import scipy.optimize as so
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy, latex2latex
s_c,t_h = sym.symbols("sigma_c T_H" )
exp1 = s_c+t_h
print(exp1)
exp2 = latex2sympy(" s_c+t_h")
print(exp2)
I get
T_H + sigma_c
s_c + t_h
although I expected exp1 and exp2 to be the same.  What am I not understanding and how can I get exp2 to be equal to T_H + sigma_C ?
Thank you

latex2sympy takes latex as an input, so you would need something like:
s_c,t_h = sym.symbols("sigma_c T_H" )
f = s_c + t_h # This is a sympy function class.
_latex = sym.latex(f) # This is now a string representing the latex of f.
f2 = latex2sympy(_latex) # Takes the latex string as an input, but could be any latex string.
print(f"""
f: {f}
f2: {f2}
""")

Note: Use backticks to wrap your code blocks in highlighted code like I did. Three backticks followed by a language (py), and then your code, and then three backticks to close it. You can use one backtick on either side if you want the code to appear inline like const this = true.

You might be getting confused because the __str__ method that is attached to all python classes defines how a class is represented when its output should be of type string. Depending on where you're using sympy, that method that sympy handled for you might have determined that you likely want latex output, but that's not what the actual object is. sym.latex will create an object that is a string, not one that can just be represented as a string.

Thank you this works perfectly and I will study it more in the morning to try to get my head around it!
